# How to insert rows in table for number of chapters

Tags: php, mysql

I have questions table in this I have 584 rows i.e 584 questions, and chapters table in this chapters table it has type column, I have chapters added for different types i.e 18 chapters for type 1 and 18 chapters for type 2 and 18 chapters for type 3, so the id's of chapter are different.

Now I have 584 questions added in the questions table for type 1, now these 584 questions I want to add in same questions table but for type 2 and questions table has column of chapter_id so the chapter_id is 80 to 97. So for each chapter if we divide 584 with chapter numbers i.e 18 the result is 32, so for each chapter 32 questions will be added with chapter id like for first 32 chapters the chapter id will be 80,for another chapter id will be 81 and so on.

But 18*32 = 576 and 584-576= 08, so by my logic 8 questions wont get insert in the table, but if I am using foreach the chapter id variable and i dose not get increment.

```
    <?php

require 'Database.php';


$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=airman_handbook','siddhi', 'siddhi');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions`");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = $sth->rowCount();


$chapterId = 80;
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $chapter) {

    while ($i <= 32)
    {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer,type,chapterId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($result['question'], $result['answer_a'], $result['answer_b'], $result['answer_c'], $result['answer_d'], $result['answer'], 2, $chapterId));
    }
    $i++;
    $chapterId ++;
}

?>

Chapter table :

id
title
type

33
Ch 1: Air Force heritage
1

34
Ch 2: Enlisted History
1

35
Ch 3: Organization
1

36
Ch 4: Air Force doctrine, AEF, Joint force
1

37
Ch 5: Emergency management
1

38
Ch 6: Standards of conduct
1

39
Ch 7: Enforcing standards and legal issues
1

40
Ch 8: Military customs, courtesies, and protocol f...
1

41
Ch 9: Enlisted force development
1

42
Ch 10: Leadership
1

43
Ch 12: Training and education
1

44
Ch 13: Resource management
1

45
Ch 14: Communicating in today's Air Force
1

46
Ch 15: Personnel programs
1

47
Ch 16: Wing support
1

48
Ch 17: Dress and appearance
1

49
Ch 18: Fit force
1

50
Ch 19: Security
1

80
Ch 1: Air Force heritage
2

81
Ch 2: Enlisted History
2

82
Ch 3: Organization
2

83
Ch 4: Air Force doctrine, AEF, Joint force
2

84
Ch 5: Emergency management
2

85
Ch 6: Standards of conduct
2

86
Ch 7: Enforcing standards and legal issues
2

87
Ch 8: Military customs, courtesies, and protocol f...
2

88
Ch 9: Enlisted force development
2

89
Ch 10: Leadership
2

90
Ch 12: Training and education
2

91
Ch 13: Resource management
2

92
Ch 14: Communicating in today's Air Force
2

93
Ch 15: Personnel programs
2

94
Ch 16: Wing support
2

95
Ch 17: Dress and appearance
2

96
Ch 18: Fit force
2

97
Ch 19: Security
2

98
Ch 1: Air Force heritage
3

99
Ch 2: Enlisted History
3

100
Ch 3: Organization
3

101
Ch 4: Air Force doctrine, AEF, Joint force
3

102
Ch 5: Emergency management
3

103
Ch 6: Standards of conduct
3

104
Ch 7: Enforcing standards and legal issues
3

105
Ch 8: Military customs, courtesies, and protocol f...
3

106
Ch 9: Enlisted force development
3

107
Ch 10: Leadership
3

108
Ch 12: Training and education
3

109
Ch 13: Resource management
3

110
Ch 14: Communicating in today's Air Force
3

111
Ch 15: Personnel programs
3

112
Ch 16: Wing support
3

113
Ch 17: Dress and appearance
3

114
Ch 18: Fit force
3

115
Ch 19: Security
3


Questions :


id
question
answer_a
answer_b
answer_c
answer_d
answer
type
chapterId


56
_______ achieved the first powered, sustained, con...
Otto Lilienthal
Orville and Wilbur Wright
The Tuskegee Airmen
Lieutenant Thomas E. Selfridge
B
1
24


57
_______ achieved the first powered, sustained, con...
Otto Lilienthal
Orville and Wilbur Wright
The Tuskegee Airmen
Lieutenant Thomas E. Selfridge
B
1
33


58
The U.S. and ___________ signed the Anti-Ballistic...
Iran
North Korea
the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics
Vietnam War
C
1
33


59
The purpose of Operation Desert Shield was to: (Ch...
defend Saudi Arabia and Persian Gulf states
respond to the attack on the U.S. Embassy in Iran
avoid a repetition of the Iranian hostage crisis
all of the above
A
1
24
```

EDIT:

```
require 'Database.php';

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=airman_handbook','siddhi', 'siddhi');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions`");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = $sth->rowCount();

$chapterId = 80;
$i = 0;

foreach ($result as $chapter) {

    while ($i <= 32)
    {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer,type,chapterId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($result['question'], $result['answer_a'], $result['answer_b'], $result['answer_c'], $result['answer_d'], $result['answer'], 2, $chapterId));

     //   $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($stmt)
        {
            echo 'row inserted';
        }
    }
    $i++;
    if($i > 32)
    {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $chapterId ++;
    if($chapterId > 91)
    {
        $chapterId = 80;
    }
}

?>
```

What can I do for this? Please help thank you.

Comment: Why not take the chapter number from the source row, and add 18 (or whatever the increment is)? Also, this could be done with a single SQL statement instead of stepping through each row. Lastly, if you could show the schema of each table, it would be easier to write and answer.

Comment: Source i.e. chapters table ids starts from 33 and till id 50 there are chapters for type 1 and for type 2 chapter id starts from 80 to 91 how to take it from source? and questions table has columns like questions, anwer_a,to answer_d and answer, type,chapter_id.@SloanThrasher

Comment: Add the schema to your question, not as a comment. By schema, I mean a list showing the column name and the type.

Comment: I think you meant 97 instead of 91. So, questions of type 1 with a table id of 33 will become table id 80, 34 => 81, etc. So add 47 to the type 1 table id to get the type 2 table id.

Comment: no I think u have misunderstood it, please check edited question. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Ok, so why not do a join with chapters to find the new chapter ID/type? Since the names match, you could find rows in chapters where the name matches but the type is not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, the following will copy the questions, and assign a (roughly) equal number to each chapter.

```
require 'Database.php';

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=airman_handbook','siddhi', 'siddhi');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `type` = 1 ORDER BY `id`;");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = $sth->rowCount();

$StartChapterId = 79;   //  Will update first through foreach, so it should be 1 less than the 1st ID.
$NumChapters = 18;
$questionsPerChapter = ceil(584 / $NumChapters);
$chapterId = 0;
$num_inserted = 0;

foreach($result as $rowno => $chapter) {
    if($rowno % $questionsPerChapter === 0) {
        $chapterId++;
        echo "<li>".$num_inserted." inserted in chapterId: ".$chapterId + $StartChapterId."</li>\n";
        $num_inserted = 0;
    }
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions (question,answer_a,answer_b,answer_c,answer_d,answer,type,chapterId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($chapter['question'], $chapter['answer_a'], $chapter['answer_b'], $chapter['answer_c'], $chapter['answer_d'], $chapter['answer'], 2, $chapterId + $StartChapterId));
    $num_inserted++;
}
echo "<li>".$num_inserted." inserted in chapterId: ".$chapterId + $StartChapterId."</li>\n";
```

As an alternative, here's a SQL statement that will make copies based on the content in the *chapters* table.

Here's a SQL statement that should copy the questions, and change the type and chapterId as you asked for.

```
INSERT INTO `questions`
(`question`,
    `answer_a`,
    `answer_b`,
    `answer_c`,
    `answer_d`,
    `answer`,
    `type`,
    `chapterId`)
SELECT `question`,
    `answer_a`,
    `answer_b`,
    `answer_c`,
    `answer_d`,
    `answer`,
    c2.`type` as `type`,
    c2.`id` as `chapterId`
FROM `questions` q
JOIN `chapters` c1
ON c1.`id` = q.`chapterId` AND c1.`type` = 1
JOIN `chapters` c2
ON c2.`title` = c1.`title` AND c2.`id` <> c1.`id`
WHERE q.`type` = 1
ORDER BY c2.`type`, c2.`id`, q.`id`;
```

Comment: First of all I think foreach cant be used here. I need some other logic.

Comment: can I divide result array into 32 arrays and then insert the questions?

Comment: @Sid, try the updated answer. Before you run the insert, run just the part starting with the *select* in phpAdmin or similar. It should show what rows would be added to the table.

Comment: I am not getting any result by select query which have shown. and I think my logic is right but its going to an infinite loop and questions are not getting inserted still I get the message as question inserted. Can u please check the edited question?

Comment: You don't get any result when running just the part starting with "select" from my answer??

Comment: If that's the case, then the data examples you posted are not what's in your tables, or the data types are mismatched. Although I appreciate you adding the data to your question, you didn't show the types of the columns, which is what I asked you to add to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141247/discussion-between-sid-and-sloan-thrasher).

Comment: helloo are you there? @Sloan Thrasher